# tests for java.time API

Tags: java, java-time

I'm currently studying java.time API by watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtD9B9TU_cY&t=2743s) by Stephen Colebourne. In the video, the lecturer mentioned that there were close to 25,000 tests written for java.time API to make sure everything works correctly.

My question is, is it possible to locate those test, because I want to learn a bit about how tests for java.time is written.

Edit:

I followed EmptyArsenal's instruction and opened up the "jdk" folder, but there doesn't seem to be a "test" folder inside. Is "test" folder located somewhere else?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to look at the tests for `java.time`, you're going to need to take a look at the [source code](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk8/) of the [OpenJDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK) project.

If download the OpenJDK source and dig into the JDK `test` directory (`jdk/test/java/time/test/java/time`), you'll see the test files.

Comment: I have opened my jdk folder but there doesn't seem to be a "test" folder inside. I have posted a screenshot of my file structure, could you please have a look? Thanks

Comment: Is that the JDK source code from the link I posted? If you just look at the JDK on your box, it's compiled already and won't include the tests. Download the OpenJDK source and you should see what I'm referring to.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know, You won't get the testing code for Oracle's Java. But You can use OpenJDK. It follows same behaviour. 
JDK8 time tests live in [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/test/java/time/test/java/time) .

Comment: Correct Answe. FYI, Oracle has declared their intention to build Oracle JDK from the OpenJDK code base, with their goal being feature-parity. Oracle reserves the right to make tweaks or patches for their paid-support customers, but also fully supports the OpenJDK project.